# Reddit Getting the api Oauth token javascript/react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, postman, reddit, reddit-access-token

I got the OAuth code from the reddit OAuth API but I am getting 401 authorization error when trying to get the token after that. I am using postman for sending the post request to https://www.reddit.com/api/v1/access_token

Here is my header and POST body which I am using in Postman.

```
//Headers
Authorization:Basic Base.Encode64(clientid:secret)
Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded
//client id and secret are those which I got by creating the app in reddit
//Body
{
    "grant_type":"authorization_code",
    "code":"authcode which I got from the get request before",
    "redirect_uri":"http://localhost:3000"
}
//I tried sending these through query string as well
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The body looks like json and not form data. The parameters would have to be sent form data format something like this. Change the body type in postman to x-www-form-urlencoded

```
grant_type=authorization_code&code=....
```

I work at Pathfix and we have Reddit on our serverless platform if you'd like to give it a shot.

Comment: Thanks..Still getting the same unauthorized 401 error. All other things are fine?? I have a doubt on authorization header syntax

Comment: The header seems correct. We use the exact same format and it works fine. Also I'm sure the redirect url matches the original one sent while retrieving the code? Also in postman, are you using the Authorization tab or headers tab? You should be using the authorization tab

Comment: I am using header tab...Which field should I use in authorization tab?

Comment: I choosed basic auth and it is giving me invalid_grant error

Comment: I am still stuck in that. Can you help me in getting the token?

Comment: If will give it a try in Postman so that I can provide you with a more accurate answer. Give me a day

Comment: Can you try it out in Pathfix, the code expires almost immediately so I’m not able to validate the process in Postman

Comment: I got the token from the other method... Thank you so much brother.. I made the script app instead and got the token by passing username paswrd instead of the code.